# How to do stemmization of Telugu using Java Lucene?

Tags: lucene, nlp, tokenize, information-retrieval

How to do **stemmization** of *Telugu* language using Java Lucene?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in stemmer for Telugu language (like Hindi have it). This means, that if you want to do some Telugu stemming you would need to implement this component yourself.

Good starting point would be take a look at this [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/anushareddymsri1/tokenizer-and-stemmer-for-telugu-language) and incorporate those techniques into Lucene `TokenFilter`.

Writing custom TokenFilter isn't that hard as it looks. You could take a look for examples [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene5/src/main/java/org/mystic/SuffixShingleTokenFilter.java)